# Installing bioinformatics packages like bowtie2 in windows through WSL

Tags: python, cmd, conda, bioinformatics, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to develop a GUI in python for analyze tRNA-Seq data which could be run in Linux and Windows. For this it is needed run some programs like: bowtie2, samtools or bedtools, which can be downloaded by anaconda easily on Linux but is a headache on Windows. This programs can't be downloaded on Windows so I had to install Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and tried to downloaded by this way.

I have developed the following python script (anaconda_setup.py) for doing this:

```
import os

#Download the file for Linux, altough this script will run only on Windows Subsystem for Linux
os.system('curl -O https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh')
#Checking the integrity of the file
os.system('sha256sum Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh')
#Running the .sh script
os.system('bash Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh')
#Compiling from source
os.system('source ~/.bashrc')
os.system('Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh')
#Using conda to install bowtie2, samtools and bedtools
os.system('conda install -c bioconda bowtie2')
os.system('conda install -c bioconda samtools')
os.system('conda install -c bioconda bedtools')
```

And then I use the following code in the main script for call the other script:

```
import os
...
os.system("wsl python3 anaconda_setup.py")
```

With this anaconda is installed correctly, but I'm not sure if it is installed on windows or in WSL. But I obtained the next error:

sh: 1: source: not found
sh: 1: conda: not found
sh: 1: conda: not found
sh: 1: conda: not found

On the other hand I have entered to WSL from CMD and I can run conda.exe and conda manually, but I can't do it in an automatically way. Moreover from CMD I can't run: "wsl conda" (error: /bin/bash: conda: command not found) but I can run wsl conda.exe without anyproblem.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or how can I fix this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Trying to do this with Python is unnecessarily complicating things. Consider writing a BASH script instead.

Comment: Thank you for your idea! But I have tried it and I obtained the same error. When I'm on wsl I can run conda command, but from cmd I can't wsl conda, same error: 1: conda: not found

Answer (score 0):

Use Linux installers for anaconda to install anaconda for wsl2

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

check if `conda` command runs, if not, the path must be exported in `.bashrc` file

```
export PATH=/home/user/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

run `conda` again, it will work now. You can install your required software using conda in wsl2.

Hope this helps you out. For more info visit this
[post](http://mmb.irbbarcelona.org/molywood/tutorials/windows_sub)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you can follow.

1. you have to have Ubuntu terminal installed. If not download it from Microsoft Store.
2. After installing Ubuntu install wget using command `sudo apt install wget`
3. Install miniconda because miniconda is lighter version of anaconda and will save up a lot of space.
4. Download miniconda installer.
   `wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh`
5. Install miniconda `bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh`
6. export PATH `export PATH=~/miniconda3/bin:$PATH`
7. Install bowtie2 using bioconda channel `conda install -c bioconda bowtie2`